# Jenkins pipeline runs recursivly due to git push file

Tags: jenkins, recursion

During the pipeline, I need to update the version file based on a new generated tag.

I got it to work, but since I am updating the repo file, the pipeline is run again, which will cause the version file to be updated and that would cause the pipeline to run again (enter recursive behavior).
Here is what I have:

```
                    if (env.GIT_BRANCH == 'master' && !env.CHANGE_TARGET) {
                        //creeate tag based on next_tag which is calculated prior to this step
                        dir('./src'){
                            writeFile file: "version.json", text: "{\"version\":\"${next_tag}\"}"
                        }
                        sh 'cat ./src/version.json'

                        withCredentials([
                            usernamePassword(
                                credentialsId: 'sc-github-app',
                                usernameVariable: 'GITHUB_APP',
                                passwordVariable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN',
                            )
                        ]) {
                            script {
                                sh 'git config --global url."https://x-oauth-basic:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.*****.com/".insteadof https://github.*****.com/'
                                sh 'git config user.email "GITHUB_APP@******.com"'
                                sh 'git config --global user.name "GITHUB_APP"'
                                sh 'git add ./src/version.json'
                                sh 'git commit -am "update version"'
                                sh 'git push origin `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`:master'
                            }
                        }
```

The last line does update the version.json file in the repo but that will trigger the pipeline to run again since the repo was updated.

Is there a way to update the file without causing the pipeline to run again?  Or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

By using github api you can disable webhook before push and after push you can set active again. Please check https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-a-webhook-configuration-for-a-repository